# How to implement git hooks server side or Gitlab level

Tags: gitlab

In gitlab how can check user is having privilege to tag for particular repo level by making git hooks in the server level.
User doesn't have privilege  to tag user should be get displayed message with proper message from hooks.

Do i need to have Apache or Nginx server for git hooks.

Answer (score 0):

Your hook could [list users for a project](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/projects.html#list-user-projects)

```
GET /users/:user_id/projects
```

That would include a [permission field](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/permissions.html).

Your GitLab webhook is any listener (so Apache or NGinX or any other program) able to process an http call.
See "[Example webhook receiver](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html#example-webhook-receiver)", which is actually a little ruby program.

Comment: Thanks Vonc, I was able to get or generate json formatted data on the basis of push tags. How the Nginx/Apache server level script looks and reads the json formatted data on the basis of push event. Means how server or script reads the json perform the activity.